# Apply delta values on nested fields

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Suppose I have record like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    statistics: {
        stat1: 1,
        global: {
            stat2: 3
        },
        stat111: 99
    }
}
```

I want to make update on record with object:

```
{
    statistics: {
        stat1: 8,
        global: {
            stat2: 6
        },
        stat4: 3
    }
}
```

And it should be added to current record as delta. So, the result record should looks like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    statistics: {
        stat1: 9,
        global: {
            stat2: 9
        },
        stat4: 3,
        stat111: 99
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make this with one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something generic or something specific?
Specific is easy, this is the generic case:

```
const updateValExpr = r.expr(updateVal);
const updateStats = (stats, val) => val
    .keys()
    .map(key => r.branch(
        stats.hasFields(key), 
        [key, stats(key).add(val(key))], 
        [key, val(key)]
    ))
    .coerceTo('object')

r.table(...)
 .update(stats => 
      updateStats(stats.without('global'), updateValExpr.without('global'))
          .merge({ global: updateStats(stats('global'), updateValExpr('global'))
 )
```

There might be some bugs here sincce it's untested but the solution key point is the `updateStats` function, the fact that you can get all the keys with `.keys()` and that `coerceTo('object')` transforms this array: `[['a',1],['b',2]]` to this object: `{ a: 1, b: 2 }`,

Edit:
You can do it recursively, although with limited stack (since you can't send recursive stacks directly, they resolve when the query is actually built:

```
function updateStats(stats, val, stack = 10) { 
    return stack === 0 
        ? {} 
        : val
           .keys()
           .map(key => r.branch(
                stats.hasFields(key).not(), 
                [key, val(key)],
                stats(key).typeOf().eq('OBJECT'),
                [key, updateStats(stats(key), val(key), stack - 1)], 
                [key, stats(key).add(val(key))]
            )).coerceTo('object')
}

r.table(...).update(row => updateStats(row, r(updateVal)).run(conn)

// test in admin panel
updateStats(r({
    id: 1,
    statistics: {
        stat1: 1,
        global: {
            stat2: 3
        },
        stat111: 99
    }
}), r({
    statistics: {
        stat1: 8,
        global: {
            stat2: 6
        },
        stat4: 3
    }
}))
```

Comment: Yeh, I've tried something like this. But the problem here is that there could be a lot of nested fields (at least 5 lvl nested).

Comment: fixed it, it seems to work in the data explorer as I wrote it. notice that you should plug it in the `update` section